# why there's a problem "no matching token found " with "{" (C1075) in C++ code

Tags: c++, visual-c++

So, there's a simple program for guessing a random number from 1 to 10:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
    int magic, guess;
    magic = rand();
    do {
        magic = rand();
    } while (!(magic > 0) && !(magic < 10));
    if ((magic > 0) && (magic < 10)) {
        do {
            std::cout << "Try to guess a random numeral from 1 to 10\n";
            std::cin >> guess;
            if (guess > magic) std::cout << "Your numeral is too big\n";
            else if (guess < magic) std::cout << "Your numeral is too small\n";
            else std::cout << "You are a magician\n";
        } while (guess != magic);
    }
        return 0;
}
```

but Visual Studio "complains" about the unknown token "{"... I even don't know what on earth is wrong, it seems to be correct. What's the issue?
P.S. I've edited the condition, now it's logical, but the error hasn't resolved

Comment: the error is in 5th line

Comment: Disregarding the fact that the condition will almost never be true, why `(!(magic > 0) && !(magic > 0)` and not `magic <= 0`? When do you expect `(magic > 0) && !(magic > 0)` to be true? How many numbers are both greater than 0 and not greater than zero?

Comment: Also, numerals are the symbols we write numbers with, such as 5, V, 五, or ۵. Numerals are not the same thing as numbers.

Comment: ahhhh, sorry, of course while (!(magic > 0) && !(magic < 10));

Comment: This must be some problem with your VS configuration.

Comment: it`s a very dumb stupid misstep, becuse i simply copy-pasted 1st part of the condition.....what a disgrace! (It didn't worth to be posted on a stackoverflow

Comment: @MakarKosenko That's equivalent to `magic <= 0 && magic >= 10`, which is never true. You probably meant `||`, but you're going to be waiting for a long time. (Generating a random number in an interval directly is much faster than waiting for one to show up by chance.)

Comment: On a related note, `!(a && b)` is equivalent to `!a || !b`, and `!(a || b)` to `!a && !b`. (These are called DeMorgan's laws and are pretty easy to verify.)

Comment: I`ve just edited the condition above in my code but there's still the error

Comment: On another related note, if you loop until some condition holds, there is no point in checking that condition immediately afterwards.

Comment: There's no brace-related problem with your code. The only explanation is I can think of is that your system headers have become corrupted and need reinstalling.

Comment: OMG, I've simply reloaded Visual Studio and there are no errors!!!!! magic

Answer (score 0):

so the solution for my unnecessary question is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{
    int magic, guess;
    magic = rand();
    do {
        magic = rand();
    } while (!(magic > 0 && magic < 10));
    if ((magic > 0) && (magic < 10 )) {
        do {
            std::cout << "Try to guess a random numeral from 1 to 10\n";
            std::cin >> guess;
            if (guess > magic) std::cout << "Your numeral is too big\n";
            else if (guess < magic) std::cout << "Your numeral is too small\n";
            else std::cout << "You are magician\n";
        } while (guess != magic);
    }
        return 0;
}
```

@molbdnilo, @Nikita Demodov, thank you very much, guys, for helping me with this problem :)
oh, yeah, and program works properly now, I've tested.